# What abbr is "bk" member within malloc.c?

Tags: c, malloc, glibc

My question is about glibc.
What is the name of the `bk` member an abbreviation for within `malloc_chunk`?

```
struct malloc_chunk {
  INTERNAL_SIZE_T      mchunk_prev_size;  /* Size of previous chunk (if free).  */
  INTERNAL_SIZE_T      mchunk_size;       /* Size in bytes, including overhead. */
  struct malloc_chunk* fd;         /* double links -- used only if free. */
  struct malloc_chunk* bk;
  /* Only used for large blocks: pointer to next larger size.  */
  struct malloc_chunk* fd_nextsize; /* double links -- used only if free. */
  struct malloc_chunk* bk_nextsize;
};
```

Refer to:
https://code.woboq.org/userspace/glibc/malloc/malloc.c.html#malloc_chunk

Comment: Maybe you can invetsigate [this](http://www.apc.univ-paris7.fr/~franco/g4doxy4.10/html/mymalloc_8cc_source.html) file

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `fd` and `bk` members are the forward and backward pointers in the doubly-linked list.

In other words, `fd` is the `next` pointer and `bk` is the `previous` pointer, as illustrated in the following three-element list:

```
forward links -->
                       _(fd)_        _(fd)_
                      /      \      /      \      _(fd)-> NULL
                     /        V    /        V    /
      head ---> item1         item2         item3
               /    ^        /    ^        /
  NULL <-(bk)_/      \_(bk)_/      \_(bk)_/

<-- backward links
```

Note that this particular example has a head and tail, with end element pointing to NULL. That's probably *not* the case for the circular list maintained by `glibc` (since it's a *circular* list), it's just used to show one method of implementation.

---

In fact, the link you provide in your question states this in no uncertain terms, starting fifty-odd lines beyond the structure definition (slightly paraphrased):

```
Free chunks are stored in circular
    doubly-linked lists, and look
    like this:
+------------------------------------------+
| Size of previous chunk, if unallocated   | <- mchunk_prev_size
+------------------------------------------+
| Size of chunk, in bytes (and some flags) | <- mchunk_size
+------------------------------------------+
| Forward pointer to next chunk in list    | <- fd
+------------------------------------------+
| Back pointer to previous chunk in list   | <- bk
+------------------------------------------+
:               <other stuff>              :
```

Comment: Thank you for quickly asking.  
In fact, I watched the simple images of malloc_chunk definition it  
but,, 
fd ≠ "Forward pointer to next chunk in list".  
bk ≠ "Back pointer to previous chunk in list".  

bk isn't initial of  backward pointers what you said...

Comment: @Halkichi: how do you deduce that `bk` is not the abbreviation for 'back pointer' and `fd` is not the abbreviation for 'forward pointer'?  The docs say that's what they're for — why do you disbelieve the docs of a project as well established and reliable as glibc?

Comment: Hmm, so the implementation would look like [circular list Art](https://susepaste.org/2243359) `:)`

Comment: @Halkichi, I have to disagree, the code shows that's *exactly* what they're used for. If you have something stating otherwise, you should probably post a link for it, but I suspect it won't be what you think it is.

Comment: I got it that I have to learn what you said. 
I was thinking that "fd" made by taking to initials.
Thank you for teaching me :)